# What is special of being countably infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I saw the proof of "there exists no function that is only continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$". The idea of the proof is to enumerate a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$. And choose a set of nested non-degenerated compact intervals.
https://holdenlee.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/can-a-function-be-continuous-only-on-rationals/

My question is: What is special of being countably infinite? E.g. for that proof, on an uncoutable set, we can just "enumerate" all points by an arbitrary index set $J$... And construct the same intervals, due to the existence of well-ordering, we can actually argue such construction works.

Comment: Well, obviously that's false. There are many uncountable sets $J $ that are the set of points of continuity of some function defined everywhere on $\mathbb R $. The strategy you suggests necessarily fails for any of those sets.

Comment: (Or what do you mean when you say that for any $J $ the construction works?)

Comment: Consider the function on $\mathbb R$ which is defined for $\frac pq \in \mathbb Q$ as $\frac 1q$ where $q$ is the positive integer value of the denominator when the fraction is in its lowest terms. Define the function as zero elsewhere. At which points is this function continuous? How does it relate to what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's hard to say what the mistake in your proof is, since we haven't seen it.

Comment: I think it is more about why a countable set can be used to do such kind of  construction as I gave in the link.

Comment: That proof in the link is based on nested interval principle and it does not have an uncountable analog.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh which property holds for only for countable times?

Comment: @XavierYang: the nested interval principle uses a (countable) sequence of nested intervals.